# Assets/shadow.js(9,19): BCE0019: 'active' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Transform'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
#pragma strict
var target : Transform;
function Start () {

}

function Update () {

    if(target.active){
        gameObject.transform.position.x= target.transform.position.x;
        gameObject.transform.position.z= target.transform.position.z;
    }
}
```

Comment: The [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) class does not have any property named `active`. Not sure how exactly you got that or what you are trying to do but check Hellium's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47809240/3785314) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check whether the gameobject is active, use [activeSelf](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html) or [activeInHierarchy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html) as follow:

```
if( target.gameObject.activeInHierarchy )
```

---

Moreover, I don't think you are able to assign individual components of the position (at least, in C#, you can't). You will have to store the position in a temporary variable :

```
var position : Vector3 = transform.position;
position.x = target.position.x;
position.z = target.position.z;
transform.position = position;
```